# Perform the Pending Writes When the App is Closed

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`Firestore` does not seem to perform the pending writes when the app is closed (killed by the system or removed by the user). Every write that is enqueued when the app is **offline** will be performed only when the app is online and running again.

I'd like to perform those writes manually in the background, so I'm using a `Work Mananger` which includes this line of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork();
```

**Full snippet:**

```
public class FirebaseSyncWorker extends Worker {

    public FirebaseSyncWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().enableNetwork();

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

**This code works for me.** It does sync user's data once in a while when the app is closed. However, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do this.

As far as I know, `enableNetwork()` is intended to re-enable network access after disabling it. My app never disables it, I just use it to perform the pending writes.

Is this a good way to achieve what I want? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So you basically want to do some stuff when the app is killed by the system or removed by the user, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes indeed. The stuff I want to do specifically is to perform all of the awaiting Firestore tasks.

Comment: So to understand better, you have multiple `Task` objects and you want to wait for each one of them untill are completed?

Comment: There is currently no API to know for sure if the client SDK thinks that all of its pending writes are fully synchronized with the server.  You can file a feature request for that, though.  If you have data to sync *from* the server, you will need to make a query for that data and wait for it to complete.

Comment: @AlexMamo No. I have edited my question. I'd like to perform all of the pending writes to the server.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I will definitely ask for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enableNetwork()` is a pretty clever way to do this. It hadn't been intended for this use, but it works.

The reason why is that `enableNetwork()` is designed to be idempotent. You can call it as often as you want and if the network is already enabled it does nothing. (`disableNetwork()` has the same kind of behavior.)

The other part of why this works is that Firestore does not start its internal work queue until you do something with it. We do this for a number of reasons, but principally this is to allow you to call `setFirestoreSettings()` before we do anything.

Your solution works because `enableNetwork()` is a call that triggers this internal startup, but then ultimately doesn't do anything because the network is already enabled.

Note that Firestore doesn't actually create a network connection if it doesn't have anything to do, so it's relatively cheap to start it up as you're doing and if there's nothing to do, it will check for pending writes and do nothing.

You could improve on this if there were an API to be able to know if we're done syncing pending writes. We've kicked this idea around but haven't settled on the API we want and haven't been able to prioritize this against other work. If this were very important to you, note that the source is open over at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/ and we're very friendly :-).

Update 2020-06-12: We added [waitForPendingWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#waitForPendingWrites()) which lets you wait until pending writes have finished.